# How to copy an existing django object to another table for temporary storage?

Tags: python, django

Basically I have an inventory system and a POS, cart and checkout.

Here are my models:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item.upc} || ${self.item.sug_ind_retail} || ({self.item.item_name}) X {self.qty} "

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.qty * self.item.sug_ind_retail

    def get_item_sales_tax(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() * .095

    def get_total(self):
        return self.get_item_sales_tax() + (self.item.sug_ind_retail * self.qty)


class TempCartItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item.upc} || ${self.item.sug_ind_retail} || ({self.item.item_name}) X {self.qty} "

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.qty * self.item.sug_ind_retail

    def get_item_sales_tax(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() * .095

    def get_total(self):
        return self.get_item_sales_tax() + (self.item.sug_ind_retail * self.qty)
```

Basically I want to save the TempCartItem's into the OrderItem model, this way I can delete all the items in the cart but save the OrderItem's when we check out a customer.

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def order_item_view(request):
    temp_order_item_form = TempCartItemForm(request.POST or None)
    
        if request.POST.get("submit"):
        temp_order_item_form.save(commit=False)
        form_upc = temp_order_item_form.cleaned_data.get('upc')
        if form_upc == '':
            messages.warning(request, "UPC is required to add to cart.")
        form_qty = temp_order_item_form.cleaned_data.get('qty')
        global customer
        customer = temp_order_item_form.cleaned_data.get('customer')

        # get item or create new one if it doesn't exist
        try:
            item = Item.objects.get(upc=form_upc, amz_truck_id=1593)

            temp_order_item_obj = TempCartItem(customer=customer, ordered=False, item=item, qty=form_qty)
            temp_order_item_obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Item successfully added to cart')
        except Exception:
            messages.warning(request, 'No item found')

        queryset = TempCartItem.objects.filter(customer=customer)

        context = {
            "order_item_form": temp_order_item_form,
            "queryset": queryset,
        }

        return render(request, "cart.html", context)

    if request.POST.get("view_cart"):
        temp_order_item_form.save(commit=False)
        customer = temp_order_item_form.cleaned_data.get('customer')
        queryset = TempCartItem.objects.filter(customer=customer)
        context = {
            "order_item_form": temp_order_item_form,
            "queryset": queryset,
        }

        return render(request, "cart.html", context)

    context = {
        "order_item_form": temp_order_item_form,
    }

    if request.POST.get("checkout"):
        temp_order_item_form.save(commit=False)

        customer = temp_order_item_form.cleaned_data.get('customer')
        ref_code = create_ref_code()

        items = TempCartItem.objects.filter(customer=customer)

        for item in items:
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(item)
            order_item.pk = None
            order_item.save()

        instance = Order.objects.create(customer=customer, ref_code=ref_code)

        for item in items:
            instance.item.add(item)


        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Order successfully created')


        queryset = Order.objects.all()

        context = {
            "queryset": queryset,
        }

        return render(request, "orders.html", context)

    return render(request, "cart.html", context)
```

In my "checkout" part of the view, how can I save all the TempCartItem's into the OrderItem's table? This way I can delete all the TempCartItem's after the order is processed so the cart is cleared but the OrderItem's are still saved.

I tried

```
      items = TempCartItem.objects.filter(customer=customer)
      for item in items:
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(item)
            order_item.pk = None
            order_item.save()
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I figured it out.

What I needed to do was create a list of objects, set the primary key to None and then bulk_create the objects from the queryset. Here's what I used:

```
    if request.POST.get("checkout"):
        temp_order_item_form.save(commit=False)

        customer = temp_order_item_form.cleaned_data.get('customer')
        ref_code = create_ref_code()

        cart_items = TempCartItem.objects.filter(customer=customer)

        new_items = []
        for item in cart_items:
            item.pk = None
            new_items.append(item)

        OrderItem.objects.bulk_create(new_items)

        order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(customer=customer, ordered=False)

        instance = Order.objects.create(customer=customer, ref_code=ref_code)

        for item in order_items:
            instance.item.add(item)

        instance.save()
        cart_items.delete()
        order_items.update(ordered=True)

        messages.success(request, 'Order successfully created')
```

Basically, it filters the TempCartItem objects by the customer, updates the field 'ordered' to True, creates a list of new_items and appends all the items into the list. Then I used bulk_create to add all the items to the new tables, filtered again by the OrderItems this time to create the Order. Then finally, I delete the items from the temporary cart table.

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this kind of thing, but it works!